# I am following Ethereum Book, but I am getting errors in the Terminal

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, parity

I am learning Ethereum Development from the Ethereum Book by Andreas. I have stumbled on the first error trying to do `$ cargo install` . I will post the instructions as an image and the errors I got.

[image: Instruction from the Ethereum Book]

When I try `$ cargo install` it first gave me a warning which is will also display below

[image: Warning Message]

The command does some compiling and then gives me the following error

[image: Error Message]

I cant really proceed since all the other commands that follow are nolonger working. Please assist if there is anything I did wrong. I am really new to this. I am not a pro-developer but working towards becoming a solidity dev.

I will really appreciate your help

Comment: Without knowing anything about the instructions in general, I'd guess that they are outdated. You are retrieving the latest code version from github but the instructions may not work with the latest version anymore. Things move and change fast around Ethereum.

Comment: Yes I noticed that things are changing alot man. Sad thing I cant find anywhere were there are updated sources. Thanks!

Comment: run beforhand an  apt-get update

Comment: Please never paste screenshots of your errors. Always copy and paste the text. It makes your question impossible to be searchable, and even harder to fix. Could you please edit your question and add the text of the error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install `cmake`.
Try running the following to install [parity dependencies](https://wiki.parity.io/Setup#dependencies):

```
apt-get install build-essential cmake libudev-dev
```

Comment: Looks like they are using a mac not linux

Answer (score 0):

When working with rust/cargo, make sure you have the dependencies installed. You can see your error even makes the suggestion:

```
is 'cmake' not installed?
```

Rust generally gives good tips as to what's going on. Be sure to read the full error as well next time.

You can either try running:
`brew install cmake` or check the download page:  https://cmake.org/install/